# XCode 4.3/4.4 typeinfo is lost for class instantiated in a dynamically loaded shared library only if class overrides a method

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm, clang, dynamic-cast

I ran in to an issue using dynamic_cast on objects instantiated in a runtime loaded shared library but only if the class contains a method that overrides another method.

I'm using Xcode 4.3 with the "Apple LLVM 3.1 Compiler"  I've compiled the same code with gcc and clang on linux and don't have the issue so I'm assuming it's a compiler bug in Xcode but has anyone seen this before?

Assume the class definitions in a header called "test3.h"

```
#pragma once

class c1
{
public:
 virtual ~c1 ();
 virtual void foo ();
};

class c2 : public c1
{
public:
 void foo () override;
};

class c3 : public c1
{
public:
};
```

Assume implementation code in a static library in a source file called "test3.cpp"

```
#include "test3.h"

c1::~c1 ()
{
}

void c1::foo ()
{
}

void c2::foo ()
{
}
```

Assume a simple dynamic library in a source file called test2.cpp

```
#include "test3.h"

extern "C"
c1 * get1 ()
{
 return new c2;
}

extern "C"
c1 * get2 ()
{
 return new c3;
}
```

Assume a simple executable application in a source file called test1.cpp

```
#include "test3.h"
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
 auto lib (dlopen ("libtest2.dylib", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL));
 auto a1 (dlsym (lib, "get1"));
 auto a2 (dlsym (lib, "get2"));
 auto f1 ((c1 * (*) ())a1);
 auto f2 ((c1 * (*) ())a2);
 auto o1 (f1 ());
 auto o2 (f2 ());
 auto d1 (dynamic_cast <c2 *> (o1));
 auto d2 (dynamic_cast <c3 *> (o2));
 auto result1 (d1 != 0);
 auto result2 (d2 != 0);
 std::cout << result1 << std::endl;
 std::cout << result2 << std::endl;
}
```

When the test program is run, result1 is false while result2 is true.  I'm expecting both result1 and result2 to be true.

Has anyone seen this or could think of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of this problem is twofold. First, the dynamic cast is using equality comparison on the RTTI objects. Second, there are two of them: one in the mainline and one in the dynamic library.

The workaround for this problem should be is to ensure that the class to be shared is in a separate dynamic link library, and is linked to by both your mainline and also all other shared libraries.

Really its a bug in the library/compiler: it shouldn't be using pointer equality for dynamic type comparison.

---

Oops. I tried this and it didn't fix my problem (g++ used to screw this up too).
Weirdly I'm correctly catching an exception in a different library, rethrowing it, catching it correctly via a base class pointer, but dynamic_cast is failing. So my recommendation does not appear to work (on OSX). Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a static library for the implementation code of the c++ classes if you intend to pass them from a `.dylib` into another application - you have to use a shared object.

The reason is that at link time you end up with private copies of the type information in both `libtest2.dylib` and `test1`; and they will be incompatible with each other.

If you want to make it work, you need to export the classes from `test3.cpp/h` in a `.dylib` that is linked to both `libtest2.dylib` and the application `test1`.

Example `Makefile`:

```
CXX=clang
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11

all: libshlib.dylib libtest2.dylib test1

clean:
    rm -f *.o test1 *.dylib

test3.o: test3.cpp test3.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -fPIC test3.cpp -o test3.o

libshlib.dylib: test3.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -fPIC -shared test3.o -o $@ -lstdc++

test2.o: test2.cpp test3.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -fPIC test2.cpp -o test2.o

libtest2.dylib: libshlib.dylib test2.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -shared test2.o -lstdc++ -L. -lshlib

test1: test1.o test3.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ test1.o -lstdc++ -L. -lshlib

test1.o: test1.cpp test3.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ test1.cpp
```